# How to identify the unfinished rectangle by image processing?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have a color image.

[image]

After several preprocessing I am able to get the following image.

[image]

However, as you have seen the door portion is not complete, only 3 lines are visible on the post processed one. Not the 4th boundary lin, because on the original photo, the color portion was missing at that part.

Now I can identify the two windows, but how to identify the door?

Is there any way to complete the unfinished part of the door as rectangle ?

The yellow ticked door is also needed to be identified.

[image]

Comment: You have not shown us any code. How can we tell you what might be wrong?  Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You want an image processing algorithm that given 3 sides of a rectangle will know to "close" the fourth one.
Suppose we give you such an algorithm, how do you expect it to differentiate between the green rectangle (the door you *want* to detect) and the red rectangle (you do not want)?

[image]

Comment: That is also concern, you are correct. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I beleive you should somehow take a step back from your processed image and identify a car blocking a view of the door.
So it boils down to the car hood identification. Maybe use high gradient color change in this area (color quickly gradients from dark grey [door] to light grey [hood] indicating last curve to be added to three straight lines of the door).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).